# Is it possible to transfer a subset of email accounts from my domain to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, migrate-data

Is it possible to transfer a subset of email accounts from my domain to Gmail?

If so, what are the steps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. The set-up is called dual-delivery, and there is an specific help article for this case: [Configure dual delivery: Legacy server primary](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178332?hl=en)

Comment: nice. Testing this now!